# AttributeError: module 'backend' has no attribute 'update_category'

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to execute some code, but it gives error:

**AttributeError: module 'backend' has no attribute 'update_category'**

here is the code,

```
def updateproduct():
    combo_material['values'] = backend.update_category()
```

Python version = 3.9.9

What's the problem here?

Comment: It means there is no method `update_category()` in the `backend` object or module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.